# VBA routine to sum all values in a range af all workbooks in a folder, to another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

What I have: A VBA routine I found somewhere and tried to adapt to my problem. I understand that this routine looks for all excel Workbooks in a folder and merges all files range H8:H27 in a new Workbook.

What I need: A routine that looks for all Excel workbooks (excluding totals.xlsx) in a folder, and sums the values in range Sheet(2)H8:H27 to the workbook totals.xlsx! sheet(2)H8:H27

I have a folder containing 67 Excel Workbooks including one Workbook called totals.xlsx;

Excluding totals.xls, the other Workbooks have huge names. Sheet number 2 in all books also have a huge name.

All the books have the same structure;

I need to sum all Workbook´s (excluding totals.xlsx) values in range sheet(2)H8:H27 to the same range in workbook total.xls! sheet (2)H8:H27;

I cannot use Consolidate tool as the limit is 50 files;

It is almost impossible to write a formula which refers to 67 workbooks having huge names, with sheet (2) also having a huge name;

So I did think about VBA routine to SUM values in range H8:H27 of all Workbooks (excluding totals.xlsx) in a folder to the same range in sheet (2) of totals.xlsx Workbook

I found and adapted the following VBA Routine. I think I am almost there, but so far I have been able to merge the values to a separated Workbook. Have no idea how to sum All Workbooks (excluding totals.xlsx)! sheet (2)H8:H27 to totals.xlsx! sheet(2)H8:H27

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    MyPath = "C:\Users\test"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then
                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count
                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        End With
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value
                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If
        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If
ExitTheSub:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `MyPath = "C:\Users\test" ... If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then` - why?? (that conditions will never be true) `On Error GoTo 0 ... On Error Resume Next` - why?? (that type of error management will cause more issues then helps you) `Cells(rnum, "A").` - both parameters should be numbers. You have so many inconsistencies and mistakes in your code, that it's really difficult understand it. Also what exactly the problem is? Please [debug](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/802/introduction-to-vba/15512/debugging#t=201609011104023996478) your code, that may help understanding issues better.

Comment: Sorry about the mistakes, condition removed;
When I run it, it works without erros;
The result is a merge in a new workbook, and I need a sum to total.xlsx

Comment: In your question you ask about `H8:H27`, but your question contains ranges in columns A and B, also what your code attempt to do is very far from what you've described... The issue with your code wasn't just that condition you've removed, but that it's almost completely lacks logic. You have 2-3 times more lines of code than that would be necessary, but still not getting the result. Please go through your code line by line and ask yourself: does this line helps me achieving my goal? Is it really necessary? Is it efficient?

Comment: Right! That was a previous test, now the range is H8:H27. I think the main idea is there. I just need some help to sum instead of merging values

Comment: Condition MyPath = "C:\Users\test" ... If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\"  Adds a slash in the end of the path if needed

Comment: you've hardcoded its value, why don't just hard code it correclty? As I've told, it just lacks logic. ` I just need some help to sum instead of merging values` - then please post only the relevant parts, not the whole stuff about opening the file and so on...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help
I said I found this routine and tried to adapted it to my problem
If I knew how to do it correctly, I wouldn’t be here desperate looking for help. 
But thanks anyway

Comment: It's not about not willing to help you. It's about we need clear questions to write a good answer. Not willing to help I wouldn't have commented anything, just downvote and leave.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Sub SUM_WBs()

```
Dim FileNameXls As Variant, i As Integer, wb As Workbook

Range("H8:H27").ClearContents

FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)
If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = LBound(FileNameXls) To UBound(FileNameXls)

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileNameXls(i))
    wb.Sheets(2).Range("H8:H27").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("H8:H27").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub